# How to post a status update to VK (vKontakte)?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, vk

I registered a standalone application on VK (vKontakte) to post a status message to a user profile through my server.

After I authorized the user profile and got a valid token and userID, I tried to post a status update to the VK wall through PHP and OAuth2, but got this error:

```
Permission to perform this action is denied for non-standalone applications: you should request token using blank.html page
```

My app is a standalone application, what could be the reason for the error message?

Answer (score 1):

- first create a standalone(Jay didnt create a standalone application)
  app,phone code etc...
- than go to this url http://vk.com/apps?act=manage click manage the
  app you just created. on settings page get the application id number.
- now you need the users token and id. this is the url that your user
  will paste to his/her browser. than you will need the page url that
  user redirected.(or find a way to do it all by your app)
  https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=YOUR-APP-ID&scope=pages,wall,offline&redirect_uri=http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&response_type=token
  more scopes can be found here https://vk.com/dev/permissions the url
  example is for wall posting,page posting etc... user will give
  permissions and thats it. now you have token and users id.(if he/she
  gave you the redirected page url just after giving your app the
  permissions)
- token url example

  https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&expires_in=0&user_id=xxxxxxxx

now to post to users wall this is the code

```
curl( 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?owner_id='.$user_id.'&friends_only=&from_group=1&message='. urlencode( $message ) .'&attachments='.$url.'&access_token='. $token );
```

to post to a page you need the page number example vk.com/public111111
and the code example is(PS:this time owner id must be negative with page number -111111)

```
curl( 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?owner_id=-111111&friends_only=&from_group=1&message='. urlencode( $message ) .'&attachments='.$url.'&access_token='. $token );
```

and the curl function here

```
function curl( $url ) {
        $ch = curl_init( $url );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );

        $response = curl_exec( $ch );
        curl_close( $ch );
        echo $response;
        return $response;
}
```

thats it. you can learn the rest all by yourself.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I somehow missed your answer. One thing I don't understand is how to access the token if the redirect domain is not my own but `https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&expires_in=0&user_id=xxxxxxxx`? Please explain. Thank you very much for your example so far.

Comment: write something like this(for your user to enable the app), 1. click the link 2. give app permissions. 3. you will be redirected to a page like this 4. copy paste the url you directed

Comment: I tried that but you don't get a token that is valid for posting updates to a users wall! I would love to see a working example but couldn't find one yet.

Comment: my app was private so, i didnt try to create a redirect handling page on my domain. if you defined your domain name on your vk app and still not working, sorry but its not my problem. the way i told you works, i know because its what i did step by step after many many maaaaaany search and lots of russian stuff.

Comment: Getting error on following mentioned steps: `[error_code] => 15 [error_msg] => Access denied: no access to call this method`. Also tried with oauth2 library, same error. I guess [wall.post method](https://vk.com/dev/wall.post) is not allowed by  webserver calls (e.g. PHP)